# Apps won't download

Tags: ios-appstore

I have a brand new iPhone SE, literally opened it two days ago, and for some reason my apps won't download or update? I do not have any paused downloads, and I made sure my iTunes works without internet, and I really do NOT want to restore my iPhone to factory settings, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already tried restarting your iPhone and it didn't work. Go to Settings -> Itunes & App Store -> tap on your Apple ID and then tap "Sign Out". Reboot your iPhone and then open the App Store. Try to download an app. It should ask your Apple ID now, so enter it and you should be good to go!